# How to send correct HTTP response on custom Error document?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers, httpresponse, errordocument

I have my site configured through `.htaccess` to do this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mydomain.com/error.php?e=403
ErrorDocument 401 http://www.mydomain.com/error.php?e=401
ErrorDocument 400 http://www.mydomain.com/error.php?e=400
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.mydomain.com/error.php?e=500
```

`error.php` logs the error and shows a user/customer friendly error page.

Also, I've added this piece of code:

```
if($_GET['e'] == '404' || $_GET['e'] == '403' || $_GET['e'] == '500' )
{   $error_no = $_GET['e']; } else { $error_no = '200'; }
header(' ', true, $error_code);
```

So when I visit `mydomain.com/pagedoesnotexist` I see the error page (but the address bar still shows the non existing URL), I receive a report that a 404 page was triggers, but I took a look at my server log file, and this is what it says:
`MY.IP.000.00 - - [date and time] "GET /pagedoesnotexistHTTP/1.1" 200 2450 "-" "USERAGENTINFO"`

Nowhere in my server log can I see anything about 404... only 200... **Why is that? How can I make it send back a 404 code?
Right now I assume that bots and such always get 200, meaning OK responses when visiting non existent sites... Or am I missing something?**

*and off topic: what does 2450 stand for? O_o*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However note that you are setting `ErrorDocument` incorrectly which is causing external redirection and returning you `200` instead of `404`, `403` etc. Set your `ErrorDocument` as follows **without domain name**:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?e=403
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?e=401
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?e=400
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?e=500
```

This will keep original not-found URL in your browser while returning correct HTTP status code.

**About your code:**

You're setting variable `$error_no` and using `$error_code` in `header()` function. You should use:

```
if($_GET['e'] == '404' || $_GET['e'] == '403' || $_GET['e'] == '500' )
{   $error_no = $_GET['e']; } else { $error_no = '200'; }
header(' ', true, $error_no);
```